# Leading images in flexbox containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been building flexbox containers - actually rows of them - and in some there were leading images. To my surprise something unexpected happens every time I put in one row flexbox containers with leading images and containers of other type (where image doesn't come first).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gurugumawaru/image/upload/v1522765892/FCC_Game_Of_Life_resized_ddofex.png"/>
  <span>Bam</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <span>Bom</span>
  <span>Bom</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <span>Bim</span>
  <span>Bim</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: tomato;
}
.image {
  height: 28px;
}
```

Please see the following example: https://codepen.io/GuRuGu/pen/KeYGwv

I'd really like to know why it happens as I'm at a loss right now.

Comment: No solution, but an observation: The lower end of the image defines where the next text element in `.container` has it's baseline; You'll see this behaviour when you change the `height` property of `.image`

Comment: Why using many elements with a  `display: inline-flex` and not a general container for all your elements with a `display: flex` in order to order and align children ?

Comment: @LorenzMerdian okay... but why does this principle work only when image comes first inside `.container`?

Comment: @Alex-dejauneetdebleu well, the idea is to use any `.container` as a separate element that can go in the same line with other elements. Using `inline-flex` allowed to make the whole `.container` an inline-element, with `display: flex` it would simply take the whole line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51203660/leading-images-in-flexbox-containers#answer-51205359) is probably the best one, as it's more flexible, but this is a quick alternative: if your images are always a fixed height (in the demo they are 28px) you can make the `container` elements the same height, and align them with `vertical-align` (because they are inline elements):

```
.container {
  height: 28px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks cool! And do you have any idea why this behaviour happened in the first place?

Comment: I agree it looks weird at first, especially the final example "Leading images & trailing images" - but having thought about it, I'm pretty sure it's correct behaviour. 

Inline items have `vertical-align: baseline` by default. The "leading image" containers are setting the baseline as 28px, so any following text nodes will adhere to that, hence the text "drops" to meet the baseline. The exception to this is text inside a container with an image, as presumably the container's `display: flex` takes precedence over the inline alignment.

Comment: Try adding the following to help visualise where the baseline is:
`* { text-decoration: underline; }`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's a solution for you, maybe I misunderstood the issue. But in my opinion, if you want to align all containers, you can wrap all containers with a wrapper and add it a `display : flex;`. With that configuration, maybe you don't need a `display: inline-flex` on containers anymore. I let them on the code below, because I don't know what are your limitations.

Here is your code with that modification. I add a `.supracontainer` class on a div wrapper around your containers. You can control the vertical alignment by using `align-items` flexbox property on supracontainer class.

```css
.container {
 display: inline-flex;
 background-color: tomato;
 align-items: stretch;
}
.supracontainer{
 display: flex;
}
.image {
 height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Leading images</h2>
<div class="supracontainer">
<div class="container">
 <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gurugumawaru/image/upload/v1522765892/FCC_Game_Of_Life_resized_ddofex.png"/>
 <span>Bam</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gurugumawaru/image/upload/v1522765892/FCC_Game_Of_Life_resized_ddofex.png"/>
 <span>Bom</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gurugumawaru/image/upload/v1522765892/FCC_Game_Of_Life_resized_ddofex.png"/>
 <span>Bim</span>
</div>
</div>

<h2>Leading image & empty containers</h2>
<div class="supracontainer">
<div class="container">
 <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gurugumawaru/image/upload/v1522765892/FCC_Game_Of_Life_resized_ddofex.png"/>
 <span>Bam</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <span>Bom</span>
 <span>Bom</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <span>Bim</span>
 <span>Bim</span>
</div>
</div>

<h2>Trailing image & empty containers</h2>
<div class="supracontainer">
<div class="container">
 <span>Bam</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <span>Bom</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <span>Bim</span>
 <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gurugumawaru/image/upload/v1522765892/FCC_Game_Of_Life_resized_ddofex.png"/>
</div>
</div>

<h2>Leading images & trailing images</h2>
<div class="supracontainer">
<div class="container">
 <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gurugumawaru/image/upload/v1522765892/FCC_Game_Of_Life_resized_ddofex.png"/>
 <span>Bam</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gurugumawaru/image/upload/v1522765892/FCC_Game_Of_Life_resized_ddofex.png"/>
 <span>Bom</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <span>Bim</span>
 <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gurugumawaru/image/upload/v1522765892/FCC_Game_Of_Life_resized_ddofex.png"/>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <span>Bim</span>
 <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gurugumawaru/image/upload/v1522765892/FCC_Game_Of_Life_resized_ddofex.png"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, looks good! Though it probably won't work in my situation - I should have mentioned that there is no telling where a separate `.container` will be used so it can't be guaranteed that there will be an outer `.supracontainer` with `display: flex` in it

Comment: Maybe you have an idea why this strange behaviour happens in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can change item order within a flex element using the `order` property:

```css
.container {
 display: inline-flex;
 background-color: tomato;
 align-items: stretch;
}
.supracontainer{
 display: flex;
}
.image {
 height: 28px;
    order:0;
}
span{
    order:1;
}
```

```html
<h2>Leading images</h2>
<div class="supracontainer">
<div class="container">
 <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gurugumawaru/image/upload/v1522765892/FCC_Game_Of_Life_resized_ddofex.png"/>
 <span>Bam</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gurugumawaru/image/upload/v1522765892/FCC_Game_Of_Life_resized_ddofex.png"/>
 <span>Bom</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gurugumawaru/image/upload/v1522765892/FCC_Game_Of_Life_resized_ddofex.png"/>
 <span>Bim</span>
</div>
</div>

<h2>Leading image & empty containers</h2>
<div class="supracontainer">
<div class="container">
 <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gurugumawaru/image/upload/v1522765892/FCC_Game_Of_Life_resized_ddofex.png"/>
 <span>Bam</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <span>Bom</span>
 <span>Bom</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <span>Bim</span>
 <span>Bim</span>
</div>
</div>

<h2>Trailing image & empty containers</h2>
<div class="supracontainer">
<div class="container">
 <span>Bam</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <span>Bom</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <span>Bim</span>
 <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gurugumawaru/image/upload/v1522765892/FCC_Game_Of_Life_resized_ddofex.png"/>
</div>
</div>

<h2>Leading images & trailing images</h2>
<div class="supracontainer">
<div class="container">
 <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gurugumawaru/image/upload/v1522765892/FCC_Game_Of_Life_resized_ddofex.png"/>
 <span>Bam</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gurugumawaru/image/upload/v1522765892/FCC_Game_Of_Life_resized_ddofex.png"/>
 <span>Bom</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <span>Bim</span>
 <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gurugumawaru/image/upload/v1522765892/FCC_Game_Of_Life_resized_ddofex.png"/>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <span>Bim</span>
 <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/gurugumawaru/image/upload/v1522765892/FCC_Game_Of_Life_resized_ddofex.png"/>
</div>
</div>
```